# Upgrade asmx Webservice to .net 4 Crystal reports 2011 sp4. Only CR2008 references available

Tags: web-services, .net-4.0, crystal-reports

I'm preping an older web service for deployment to a new server running .net 4 and CR Runtime verion 13_4 (CR2011SP4) x64 runtime.

I've installed the CR extensions for VS2010 from Here:
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_4.zip

I've changed the project .net runtime to 4.0 in Project->Properties->Compile->Advanced Compile Options.

When I go to replace the CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine and CrystalDecisions.Shared to the new versions that should now be available, I don't find them. The only versions of those libraries are 12.0.2000.0. Per this page, they should be 14.0.4xxx.x http://victoriayudin.com/2009/05/25/crystal-reports-service-packs-and-versions/

So I'm not sure if this is an CR SDK install problem, a project configuration problem, or somthing entirely unexpected.

Does anyone have an ideas or links to help me get to the bottom of this?

Comment: I just installed this package: http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_4.exe and now I am seeing CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine v13.0.2000.0 libraries for .net 2, but nothing for .net 4.0.